# Why use SFINAE instead of function overloading?

Tags: c++, sfinae, enable-if

I'm trying to understand `std::enable_if` , there is a example at [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) , what is advantage of this using than function overloading ?

```
struct T {
    enum { int_t,float_t } m_type;
    template <typename Integer,
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value, int> = 0
    >
    T(Integer) : m_type(int_t) {}
> 
    template <typename Floating,
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<Floating>::value, int> = 0
    >
    T(Floating) : m_type(float_t) {} // OK
};
```

```
struct T1 {
        enum { int_t, float_t } m_type;
        T1(int) :m_type(int_t)
        {
            cout << "int ctor" << endl;
        }

        T1(float) :m_type(float_t)
        {
            cout << "float ctor" << endl;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Your version doesn't handle  `double`, `long`, `long long`...

Comment: Function overloading only works for `int` and `float`. Templates work for `int8_t`, `uint8_t`, `int16_t`, `uint16_t`, `int32_t`, `uint32_t`, `int64_t`, `uint64_t`, `float` and `double`.

Comment: In addition you accept custom types with conversion to `int` (or `float`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two examples are not the same.  With the first example, the class will except any integer or floating point type **exactly**. With your second example, you only take in a `int` or `float` meaning if you passed a `long long` or `double`then you have the potential for a narrowing conversion which could cause you to lose data.  That doesn't matter with the code you are using, but it can and should be watched out for.

You will also get ambiguities when using a a type that could be converted to either a `float` or an `int`.  For example

```
T1 foo{0l};
```

wont compile but

```
T foo{0l};
```

will.

Comment: The example class does not store the actual data. It stores whether the constructor was called with an integer or floating point type. So there's no danger of data loss.

Comment: @Darhuuk True.  Added that it doesn't actually apply to this example.

Answer (score 0):

In this case there's indeed not really an advantage, because integer types would be converted to e.g. `int` first and then the correct overloaded constructor would be called.

However, imagine you want to create a function which only accepts integers. It should return the type of integer it received as argument. In that case manually creating >10 overloads is just error-prone/silly/annoying/... Instead, you'd write something like:

```
template <typename Integer,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value, int> = 0>
Integer doMagic (Integer a) {
  return a;
}
```